# Get data from two different struct

Tags: go

Have this struct of User and Post and I try to make Name from User to be included within Post Struct when a user create a new post.

```
type User struct {
    ID             int
    Name           string
    Created        time.Time
}

type Post struct {
    ID int
    PostTitle string
    PostDesc string
    Created time.Time
}
```

How can I create something connected between this two struct such as Author of the Post ?

The goal is try to get the name of the post author which from User struct with the code below:

```
post, err := app.Models.Posts.GetPost(id)
```

GetPost() just run SELECT query and scan row

Comment: What is the schema of the Users and Posts relations (tables)? Based on the data you've provided, these two defined types are not related. I'm sure you have established a relationship between these two entities in your mind, but may not have implemented them in the schema. 

I think we both are likely visualizing it as a Post contains ID, PostTitle, PostDesc, and Created time as well as an Author which is a foreign key to the ID of a User. Perhaps [What is a Foreign Key?](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/what-is-a-foreign-key/) could help.

Comment: Agreed with above but that implies the question has nothing to do with go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is without any ORM.
It's a simple query that can return multiple rows. You've to scan the whole resultset and map each column on the struct's fields.

> Keep in mind to always check for errors.

Below you can find the solution:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Post struct {
    ID        int
    PostTitle string
    PostDesc  string
    Created   time.Time
    UserID    int
    User      User
}

type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Created time.Time
}

func main() {
    conn, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // get MAX id
    var id int
    conn.QueryRow(`SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts`).Scan(&id)

    // insert
    sqlInsertStmt := `INSERT INTO posts (id, post_title, post_desc, created, user_id) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)`
    if _, err = conn.Exec(sqlInsertStmt, id+1, "TDD", "Introduction to Test-Driven-Development", time.Now(), 1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // read
    rows, err := conn.Query(`SELECT posts.id, post_title, post_desc, posts.created, users.id, users.name, users.created FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var posts []Post
    for rows.Next() {
        var post Post
        if err = rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.PostTitle, &post.PostDesc, &post.Created, &post.User.ID, &post.User.Name, &post.User.Created); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        posts = append(posts, post)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range posts {
        fmt.Printf("author name: %q\n", v.User.Name)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

#### Edit

I've also included an example of INSERT in Postgres. To achieve it, we've to use the `db.Exec()` function, and provide the parameters.

> Pay attention to how you construct the query as you can get a SQL-Injection vulnerability.

Lastly, in a real-world scenario, you shouldn't lookup for the MAX id in the `posts` table but should be automatically generated.

Comment: This helps thank you. But how can I do INSERT query with similar method.

Comment: I need to get user_id during post submit right ? 

Do this `posts.user_id=users.id` means get value posts.user_id which is equal to user.id ?

Comment: You're right! The `posts.user_id=users.id` condition is to fetch only records that have a relationship with records in the other table. It's the condition for the JOIN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try to this solution, maybe it resolves your issue.

First, I defined the structs in this way:

```golang
// "Post" belongs to "User", "UserID" is the foreign key
type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        int
    PostTitle string
    PostDesc  string
    Created   time.Time
    UserID    int
    User      User
}

type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Created time.Time
}
```

In this way, you can say that `Post` belongs to `User` and access the User's information within the `Post` struct.
To query the records, you've to use `Preload("User")` to be sure to eager load the User records from the separate table.

> Keep attention to the name you pass in as the argument in `Preload`, as it can be tricky.

Lastly, you'll be able to access data in the embedded struct (with the `dot` notation).
Below, you can find a complete working example (implemented with the use of Docker):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

// "Post" belongs to "User", "UserID" is the foreign key
type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        int
    PostTitle string
    PostDesc  string
    Created   time.Time
    UserID    int
    User      User
}

type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Created time.Time
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Post{})

    newPost := &Post{ID: 1, PostTitle: "Golang", PostDesc: "Introduction to Golang", Created: time.Now(), UserID: 1, User: User{ID: 1, Name: "John Doe", Created: time.Now()}}
    db.Create(newPost)

    var post Post
    db.Preload("User").Find(&post, 1)
    fmt.Printf("author name: %q\n", post.User.Name)
}
```

Let me know if I answered your question!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I achieved this without gorm cause im not using it

Comment: Are you using plain SQL queries?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to learn without using ORM as coming from django background.